# can not load rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems

I just cloned a new repo and did bundle install and bundle update. i dont know why i am getting following error when i do bundle exec rails c. i am using rails version 5.0.1

```
bundler: failed to load command: rails (/Users/user123/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rails)
Gem::LoadError: railties is not part of the bundle. Add it to Gemfile.
  /Users/user123/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.6/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:336:in `block (2 levels) in replace_gem'
  /Users/user123/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/bin/rails:22:in `<top (required)>'
```

I am in my project directory too. also when i do rails c i get

```
Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]   
.....
```

gemfile looks like below

## Specify your gem's dependencies in wellness_client.gemspec

```
gemspec

gem 'roll_out','~> 1.10.0'
gem 'roll_out-jira'
gem 'philter', '~> 1.11.0'

gem 'rake', '~> 11.0'

# Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
gem 'byebug'
# An IRB alternative and runtime developer console
gem 'pry', '~> 0.9.12'
# Walk the stack in a Pry session
gem 'pry-stack_explorer', '~> 0.4.9'
# Simple, feature rich ascii table generation library
gem 'terminal-table', '~> 1.5', '>= 1.5.2'
# Great Ruby dubugging companion: pretty print Ruby objects to visualize their structure.
# Supports custom object formatting via plugins
gem 'awesome_print', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.1'

# BDD for Ruby
gem 'rspec', '~> 3.1'
# Code coverage for Ruby 1.9+ with a powerful configuration library and automatic merging of coverage across test suites
gem 'simplecov', '~> 0.7.1'
# factory_girl provides a framework and DSL for defining and using factories - less error-prone,
# more explicit, and all-around easier to work with than fixtures.
gem 'factory_girl', '~> 4.0'
# Faker, a port of Data::Faker from Perl, is used to easily generate fake data: names, addresses, phone numbers, etc.
gem 'faker', '~> 1.6', '>= 1.6.6'
```

Thanks

Comment: does `rails -v`work?

Comment: Can you post your gemfile?

Comment: yes. when i do rails-v i get Rails 5.0.1

Comment: updated question with gemfile

Comment: That's a strange looking Gemfile. 1) It has no source. Normally there's a line like `source 'https://rubygems.org'` at the top of a Gemfile, or else something to designate the gemserver. 2) It has a gemspec line. Is this a rails app? If it says gemspec, I'd think this was a gem. 3) That Gemfile doesn't include a `gem 'rails'` line. Is there a .gemspec file here too? If so, please post?

Comment: Are you trying to put a rails app inside a rubygem?

Answer (score 0):

Your gemfile does not have a rails version specified. railties is a dependency of rails, it should be enough to have a rails version specified to fix this. Supposing that project was written with rails 5 in mind, add this line to your gemfile:

```
gem 'rails', '5.0.1'
```

Now re-run `bundle install` and rails console/server should work.